# Temporarily suspend or deactivate an interval stream used in futures::select

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stream

I'm currently writing an application that is heavily based on repeating tasks at well-defined frequencies. As such, I chose to set up my main loop something like this:

```rust
use async_std::stram::interval;
use futures::{pin_mut, select, stream::StreamExt};

let interval_a = interval(duration_a).fuse();
let interval_b = interval(duration_b).fuse();
pin_mut!(interval_a, interval_b);

loop {
  select! {
    _ = interval_a.next() => {
      // perform task A
    }
    _ = interval_b.next() => {
      // perform task B
    }
    complete => break,
    default => std::thread::sleep(some_time), // though due to the async select! this may not yield much benefit
  }
}
```

The problem now is that I have one task that needs to be executed at a high frequency (let's say task B), but only if a certain condition is met (which is determined in another interval, e.g. task A).

A straightforward way is of course to include an `if` condition in task B to simply `continue;` but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to suspend `interval_b` instead, so that it won't get `select!`ed unless it's relevant.

My first impulse was to initialize the respective stream with `let mut interval_b = futures::stream::pending().fuse()`, then if the relevant condition in task A is met, I'd assign the proper `interval_b = interval(duration_b)`, or reset it to a `Pending` if the condition is not met any more after a while. However, this leads to typing issues, as a `Fuse<Pending<Interval>>` is not a `Fuse<Interval>`, so one can not suddenly assign a value of the latter to a variable of the former.

I was wondering if some `dyn`-based type declaration was possible, i.e.

```rust
let mut interval_b: 
  Box<dyn mut futures::stream::FusedStream<Item = async_std::stream::Interval>>>
  = Box::new(futures::stream::pending().fuse())`
```

Yet while I can declare `interval_b` this way, I cannot figure out how to assign a boxed fused interval to it and run into issues with the pinning of the boxed value in the `select!` as well.

So I've been wondering, is what I want to achieve even possible in Rust, and if so, what's the issue with my present approaches.

Comment: FWIW, [Tokio's `select`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.1.0/tokio/macro.select.html) has preconditions that you can attach to each branch.